# AirPort for WiFi, DLINK for hardwired

Tags: dhcp, dynamic-ip, d-link, apple

sorry in advance for such a basic question...

I have the following daisychain:

Phone Socket <-> DSL modem <-> AirPort Extreme <-> DLINK 4 port hub

I followed only the *very basic setup* instructions for both AirPort and DLINK.

AirPort is successfully assigning dynamic 10.0.1.x/40 addresses to wireless devices:

- iPhone - can access internet :^)
- iPad - can access internet :^)
- WiFi radio - can play internet streams :^)
- a Laptop (Win XP), using WiFi :^)

DLINK is sucessfully assigning dynamic 192.168.0.10x addresses to hardwired devices:

- Desktop PC (Win 7)- can access internet :^)
- A network attached storage unit - can be accessed by PC :^)
- The same laptop as above, if I turn off the WiFi and connect hardwired - can access internet :^)

Devices connected by WiFi cannot "see" devices hardwired. For example:

- If the laptop is on WiFi (AirPort), I cannot RDC the desktop PC, but I can if I disable the WiFi and hardwire the laptop to the DLINK
- I cannot VNC the desktop PC from the iPad
- However, I can PING the wireless the devices (10.0.1.x) from the PC (192.168.0.10x)

I guess my question is: how do I set up the AirPort and/or DLINK so I can communicate "upstream" from the AirPort-attached-devices to the DLINK-attached-devices?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your D-Link is not a "hub," but a NAT router. You can switch its current connection to the Airport where it is connecting from the Airport to the WAN port of the D-Link to one of the D-Link's LAN switch ports instead. You just have to turn off the DHCP functionality of the D-Link which will then let the Airport service all the devices connected across both network devices.

Comment: Thanks! I figgered it must be something simple. Also, I appreciate the correction on terminology.

Comment: PS - does the DLINK get an IP from the AirPort? The 192.168.0.1 doesn't work any more to configure the DLINK, and I can't detect any responsive 10.0.1.x that's not associated with any of the other known devices. Everything's working, so I really don't need to fuss with the DLINK config, but I'm curious if it's possible. Thanks!

Comment: No need to access the D-Link with the current working configuration. It's rendered a "dumb switch" versus its original product design as a NAT router, which yo already have in the Airport. Just keep in mind of that, if you ever need support from D-Link that it is not a configuration that the manufacturer will typically support since the D-Link was designed and marketed as a NAT router - not a "dumb" switch.